# New router and now IE and Firefox won´t work (but IE 64 bit does...?)

Tags: internet-explorer

The other day I bought a new wireless router because my old one had finally had it.  My PC recognizes is and says I have internet - fully connected - but for some reason IE won´t and neither will Firefox (I thought it was just IE crashing so I installed Ff to no avail).  If I open IE 64 bit it works fine but then I can´t play anything with Flash player so it is largely useless anyway.  I am at my wits end!

ps. my husband´s Mac has no probs so it´s not the router.

Comment: proxy settings?

Comment: While you're waiting for solution, I recommend that you check out the [site](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer10_square.html) for beta 64bit Flash. Another interesting program could be [64bit Java](http://java.com). It's needed to run Java applets from 64bit browsers.